# "Глядя на это". Утратило ли деепричастие глагольное значение?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

**Я был готов застрелиться() глядя на это.**

Можно ли задать к данному деепричастию вопрос как/каким образом?

Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Я был готов застрелиться, глядя на это.**

Оборот в роли обстоятельства времени, соответствует придаточному предложению: Я был готов застрелиться, когда глядел на это.

Сравнить: Он шел не оглядываясь. Это **обстоятельство образа действия** (как?) **в основном сообщении**, нет паузы, оборот является смысловым центром высказывания.

Правило  [Розенталь. Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113)

1) Деепричастный оборот, как правило, обособляется.

Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот **не обособляется**:
1) если деепричастный оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) **тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания**: Она сидела чуть откинув голову (Марк.) — указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела с откинутой головой; Жили Артамоновы ни с кем не знакомясь (М. Г.) — важно, что жили без всяких знакомств;

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко, то не-а. Не утратило. Не "каким образом", а всё ж таки "что делая".

Comment: Следавательно, запятая нужна.

Comment: Само собой О_о...